# Как сделать форму подстановки значений из связанной таблицы в combobox

Tags: c#, sql

Как сделать форму подстановки значений из связанной таблицы в combobox чтобы показывались не id а значение этого id (например название).
[image: 1]
Есть например 2 таблицы Машины и Работники которые связаны связью ( 1-много) и мы ручками добавляем запись через несколько combobox-ов с помощью sql в таблицу работников и вместо id_машины мы должны видеть название машины а когда запрос уже отправляться он должен уже вставить id.Есть ли какие-то легкие решения или функции встроеные в sql для этого?

Comment: Это можно сделать множеством разных способов. Чтобы получить конкретный ответ вы должны указать, что используете для работы с БД: ado.net, entity framework, что-то ещё? В каком виде у вас представлены данные, полученные из БД? Из какого GUI-фреймворка combobox: WinForms, WPF, MAUI, что-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляй в combobox и id и его значение только так чтобы id было за видимой частью combobox

```
comboBox3.Items.Add((reader1.GetValue(1).ToString() + "                           ~" + reader1.GetValue(0).ToString()));
```

а потом перед выполнение запроса делаешь split

```
                    {
                        comboBox3.Text = comboBox3.Text.Split('~')[1];
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {


                    }
```

Comment: Вы это серьёзно?

Answer (score 0):

Пример использования combobox для показа "названия" и записи "Ид"

```
 /// <summary>Заполнить источник ComboBox данными из таблицы из указанных колонок</summary>
/// <param name="cmb">ComboBox - получатель</param>
/// <param name="tbl">таблица-источник</param>
/// <param name="displayName">наименование колонки для DisplayMember</param>
/// <param name="valueName">наименование колонки для ValueMember</param>
/// <returns></returns>
    public static bool SetColumnToComboBox(ComboBox cmb, DataTable tbl,
                                string displayName, string valueName = null)
    {
      int idx = 1;
      cmb.Items.Clear();
      int iDisplayCol = tbl.Columns.IndexOf(displayName);
      int iValueCol = (valueName != null) ? tbl.Columns.IndexOf(valueName) : -1;
         if (iDisplayCol < 0) {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("SetColumnToComboBox. Display Column not found", displayName);
             return false; }
         for (int iRow = 0; iRow < tbl.Rows.Count; iRow++)
         {
             string sValue;
             int iId;
             try
             {
                 iId = (valueName != null) ? 
                                ((tbl.Rows[iRow][iValueCol] != null) ?
                                              (int)tbl.Rows[iRow][iValueCol]
                                                                                  : -1)
                                              : idx;
                 sValue = (tbl.Rows[iRow][iDisplayCol] != null) ? tbl.Rows[iRow][iDisplayCol].ToString() : "<>";
                 if (sValue.Length > 0) cmb.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(iId, sValue));
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Ошибка SetColumnToComboBox" + ex.Message); }
             idx++;
         }
         return true;
     }
```

Допустим, Ваша таблица работников называется "tblWorker" и имеет поля Id,Name. Поле "Name" должно быть видно в списке.
Такую функцию можно использовать так:

```
  SetColumnToComboBox(cmbSelectWorker,"tblWorker","Name","Id")
```

Соответственно свойства контрола cmbSelectWorker "DisplayMember" - наименование работника и "ValueMember" идентификатор работника. Можно использовать  для записи в таблицу "Машины"